# How to create a script on MacOS automator to Watermark each file in a folder with a different set of watermarks?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, automator

I am trying to create a script to watermark a group a PDF files in a folder, each PDF has to have a unique watermark.

All the PDFs are in one folder, all the watermarks are in .png located in another folder.

I currently have watermark script which I found on [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6622756?page=2), but this was made to watermark all files with one watermark only.

What I need is a way to watermark each PDF file with it's own different watermark (there are 400 pdfs and 400 different watermarks)

Please help if you can, Thank You.

Answer (score -2):

[Automator Workflow 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crAbU.png)

[Automator Workflow 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F91l.png)

[Automator Workflow 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG9Mt.png)

I have done a folder action workflow with Automator including some AppleScript an JavaScript. Maybe you can just adjust it to your needs.

It sets a dropped in Watermark file (PDF in my case) size A4 on the right half of the 1st page of another PDF size A3. BTW it extracts the individual name of the document from the PDF (job description number) and renames the final file.